# Navigating race condition in Verilog using blocking assignment

Tags: verilog, flipflop, system-verilog

If I want to create a **pipelined** flip-flop (FF) structure, where data from the input is at the output after 2 clock cycles.
This is a top-down **block**ing assignment code.

```
module circuit (
    input wire clk,
    input wire rstn,
    input wire [7:0] din,
    output reg [7:0] dout
);
    reg [7:0] mid;
    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (!rstn) begin
            mid  = 0;
            dout = 0;
        end else begin
            mid  = din;
            dout = mid;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Schematic for this code:

[image]

If I use blocking assignment in **reversed** order:

```
module circuit (
    input wire clk,
    input wire rstn,
    input wire [7:0] din,
    output reg [7:0] dout
);
    reg [7:0] mid;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (!rstn) begin
            mid  = 0;
            dout = 0;
        end else begin
            /*
            mid <= din;
            dout <= mid;
            */
            dout = mid;
            mid = din;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Then I get a schematic like this, which is **identical** to what would I get if I were to use non-blocking assignments.

[image]

If I keep the ordering in mind, can I use the blocking assignments to get the behavior from the circuit for which I usually use the NBA? For example, avoiding [race conditions](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf), sampling asynchronous input, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to follow the advice in the paper:

> Guideline: Use nonblocking assignments in always blocks that are
> written to generate sequential logic

Then you never need to worry about race conditions or other unexpected simulation/synthesis issues.  For sequential logic, use this, for example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (!rstn) begin
        mid  <= 0;
        dout <= 0;
    end else begin
        mid  <= din;
        dout <= mid;
    end
end
```